# Can't connec to the Internet

Tags: networking

I just installed xubuntu 14.04. I'm using a VPN on my host machine. I can't connect to the internet either with the VPN on or off. I tried pinging a public IP address with no luck. I have stopped and restarted networking.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? Can you connect to the internet before starting the VPN? What are the contents of the routing table before and after? Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: Even though you found the solution to your problem, it is impossible to figure out what the original problem was from your question. This question is unlikely to help others unless edited with more information.

Comment: @Fabby, Thanks Fabby, I added the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Edit `NetworkManager.conf` by executing:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
   ```
2. Comment out `dns=dnsmasq` with "#"
3. reboot.

Comment: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/610050/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... ;-)  Notice the eight spaces in front of the command (needed when using bulleted lists).